# VMWare player does not detect GParted live CD iso file

Tags: vmware-player, live-cd

I have a VMWare Player virtual machine where I am trying to change partitions of my Windows 7 VM hardrive using GParted. I downloaded a GParted live CD from [here](https://gparted.org/download.php). I tried this with both *-i686 and *-amd64 versions.

The problem is that VMWare Player VM does not detect the bootable ISO at all. I added the ISO file like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHR8I.png). When I run the VM and check its setting then CD/DVD (SATA) has a checkmark next to it so I presume it is connected. But the ISO is nowhere to be found when I try to [change boot order in PhoenixBIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dBmZ.png). So I cannot run GParted to change partitions.

I´ve already checked that both *-i686 and *-amd64 ISO files are bootable with MagicISO.

Has anyone dealt with this? I´ve tried both my Windows 7 VM and Ubuntu VM. In both I went into PhoenixBIOS and results were the same.

Comment: It's not going to show the ISO (disc) in the BIOS, but it does show `CD-ROM Drive`, which is set _after_ the hard drives in the boot order.  You can also trying pressing `Esc` at the boot logo to manually select the boot device.

Comment: BACON I think I tried ESC. I didnt get any option other than Hard drive.

Comment: Then I would try moving `CD-ROM Drive` before `Hard Drive` in the boot order.  Otherwise, is this a BIOS or EFI virtual machine?  If the latter, maybe there's some "legacy boot" option that needs to be enabled to allow booting from a disc.

Comment: BACON I’ll try moving the CD-ROM that didnt occure to me. 
Unfortunately I do not know the type. The machine was not mine originally and its a few ywars old. How do I tell the difference?

Comment: I'm saying in your third screenshot showing the boot order you would use the `+`  and `-` keys to move `CD-ROM Drive` ahead of `Hard Drive` in the boot order.

Comment: BACON That did it. Thank you very much.